# How can I get coordinates of an SVG by clicking on some point?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, svg, onclick

I am new to SVG and I am trying to generate an event in order to get the coordinates of the click when I click on the SVG. I have multiple questions:

- I am using angular and I am not sure if this is possible keeping my function in the TS file or I have to create a  or something. I have also seen that some people use jQuery, but I am not sure what this technology is. It is possible to it in angular?
- I have tried using the OnClick attribute, from the SVG components, but I would like to know if there is possible to cover al the SVG space (in case this is not possible I may create a rectangle from all the viewbox dimensions with opacity 0?)

This is what I have tried as I have done before with click events from other components:

```
<rect [attr.x]="esquina_cuadriculaX" [attr.y]="esquina_cuadriculaY" [attr.width] = "ancho_cuadricula" 
[attr.height] = "alto_cuadricula" fill="none" 
stroke="black" stroke-width="350" [attr.onclick]="clicked($event)" />
```

And on the TypeScript file I have the function itself:

```
  clicked($event :any){
    console.log("x: "+$event.clientX+" y:"+$event.clientY);
}
```

But I get the error "Property '$event' does not exist on type 'GraficaComponent'." where GraficaComponent is of course my component.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

try binding your event-handler like this (use round parathesis an correct event name 'click'):

```
<rect [attr.x]="esquina_cuadriculaX" [attr.y]="esquina_cuadriculaY" [width] = "ancho_cuadricula" 
[height] = "alto_cuadricula" fill="none" 
stroke="black" stroke-width="350" (click)="clicked($event)" />
```

Comment: I did not mention that this rect is inside a SVG, that why I used the onclick, which is an attribute of SVG elements. It works with (click), but the coords do not match with the SVG coords, would be possible to get the SVG coords?

Comment: mmh interesting, maybe try to bind it without calling the method: `[attr.onclick]="clicked"`.
I am not sure whether function references can be pased to attributes though. Also, you would have no acces to the `this.`-Context of the class unless you convert the clicked-function into an arrow function